# jQuery .ajax call with javascript onclick event not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code and it works fine while isolated into the 2 small scripts I have below. Basically I push a button which makes a call to the database to delete a row.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function removeNo(){
$.ajax({url: "removeno.php",
type: "post",
});        
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<input class='mybutton' type='submit' onclick='removeNo()' value='Remove' />
</body>
</html>
```

removeno.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id='24453305255'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Now when I take the HTML button part and put it into a larger PHP script it does not work. The entry that I would like to delete is still in the database. I'm still calling the same PHP file 'removeno.php'. The Javascript is in the header just the same as it is above. All files are in the same directory, and I've made sure to include the 'config.php' connection file in the PHP script.

I've not posted my full PHP scripts as it's several hundred lines, however the whole page evaluates to this piece, and evaluates through the "if" maze I have below. It even displays the button as it should with the value of "remove". It would display "submit" if it didnt evaluate correctly. Am I calling this function correctly within this PHP script?

```
echo "<td>"; //Main Button 
if($isleadership == 2) {
      if($reviewed == "Yes") {
          echo "<input class='mybutton' type='submit' onclick='removeNo()' value='Remove' />";
       } else if ($reviewed == "No") {
           echo "<input class='mybutton' type='submit' name='".$a."' value='Submit' />";
       }
}
```

Comment: May you post your complete file, with JavaScript and PHP?

Comment: There's got to be some difference in the HTML output from PHP vs. your plain HTML example, but it's not the submit button. Your `echo` statement outputting the button is exactly equivalent to the HTML you posted at the top of your question.

Comment: I can post the entire file. Is there a way to attach it? Or quickly format it for SO instead of spacing over 4 times on each line?

Comment: You can use http://www.pastebin.com to post your entire file.

Comment: Full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/jPC91EyS

Comment: Did you verify if the button code is being generated? Take a look in your soure code (in browser). What browser are you using? If you are using firefox, use Firebug to see if some error is being thrown.

Comment: The button code is being generated and looks like it should when I view source on the live version of the page. Im using Firefox. Installing Firebug now. I've never used it.

Comment: Install it and activate it. Reload your page and push the button to see if some error is generated.

Comment: Firebug is a must have tool for web development ;)

Comment: Ok, its installed and I refreshed the page and then clicked the input button. In the console I have a link to the page and "POST" in red. UPDATE - its actually a link to the php script, not the current page in red.."removeno.php"

Comment: Ah I see. Once I expand the link to the php script it gives this "A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element."